# Camara or Gallery Button to upload selected photo

Tags: php, android, button, android-camera, android-gallery

I want to upload a photo to my server.
The code for the camera works perfectly but when I implement the new button to select an image from the gallery doesn't work.

foto is a string where I put the name of the file to upload to server.

I've implement two buttons Camera and Gallery:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(foto));
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);

            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE); 
            break;

        case R.id.btGallery:

            Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            Uri output1 = Uri.fromFile(new File(foto2));
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output1);

            startActivityForResult(i, 2);

            break;
    }
}
```

The camara button and action works and upload the image to the server.

onActivityResult function is:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    switch(requestCode) {

        case 1:
            iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(foto));
            File file = new File(foto);

            if (file.exists()) {
                UploaderFoto nuevaTarea = new UploaderFoto();
                nuevaTarea.execute(foto);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se ha realizado la foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;

        case 2:
            File file2 = new File(foto2);
            if (file2.exists()) {
                UploaderFoto nuevaTarea = new UploaderFoto();
                nuevaTarea.execute(foto2);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DENTRO EXISTS GALLERY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FUERA EXISTS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;

    }

}
```

In ActivityResult enter in the if loop and show the Toast, but never pass the info to the UploaderPhoto.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use HTML5 and the camera of the device, there is an HTML5 feature for this. Example:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

from here: https://coderwall.com/p/epwmoa